# Data structure for fast retrieval of middle element

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I need to solve a problem where I can insert left and right. And then extract from the data in the middle of the array.

I already tried to solve this with using linkedlist. However this approach was too slow to be accepted as an solution.

What data structure would you suggest I use if i need fast insertion at the beginning and the end of a list as well as fast retrieval of the middle element?

Here is the code I've already tried with:

```
private static void middleQueue(int loopLength, String[] commandsArray) {

    LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();

    int counterSize = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < commandsArray.length; i++) {
        if(commandsArray[i].equals("R")){
            linkedList.add(commandsArray[i+1]);
            i++;
            counterSize++;
        }
        else if(commandsArray[i].equals("L")){
            linkedList.addFirst(commandsArray[i+1]);
            i++;
            counterSize++;
        }
        else if(commandsArray[i].equals("E")){
            if((linkedList.size() & 1) == 0)
                System.out.println(linkedList.remove((counterSize / 2)-1));
            else
                System.out.println(linkedList.remove((counterSize / 2)));

            counterSize--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can keep 3 pointers (first, middle and last elements) and the length of the list.

Comment: What is "the middle element"? The element that is exactly in the middle of the current list, or the element that is where the original structure started? If your list is `0`, and you add `1, 2, 3` to the right, and `-1` to the left, i.e. have `-1, 0, 1, 2, 3`, would then `0` or `1` be your middle element?

Comment: The bookkeeping for that middle pointer is quite simple: every time 2 consecutive insert occurs at the beginning (rest. the end) of the list, set the middle pointer to its predecessor (resp. successor)

Comment: Depending on what you need, you might just use two linked lists, or maybe a self-balancing binary tree (root being the middle element).

Comment: @tobias_k If the list is of equal length, the middle element is at index size/2-1, if not it is at index size/2

Comment: LinkedHashMap for better speed? Even in this case you will not get the positional index and will have to create added logic to iterate to the designated position to get the element.

Comment: Do you just want to _retrieve_, or _remove_ the middle element?

Comment: Retrieve and remove @tobias_k

Comment: @BorisGrunwald In that case, forget about the ArrayList idea... but self-balancing binary search tree should work fine, all operations should be O(logn) there.

Comment: So it seems that a linked list with references to the first,last and middle node would be the best choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take 3 pointers first, middle, last pointer.
Then there are 2 cases:

1. if you add from first 
   ans. You need to shift the middle pointer to left side then its current position.
2. if you add from last
   ans. You just need increase the middle pointer to its next.

Comment: I think the idea is clear, but how do you implement this in Java? Can you access and hold a reference to the internal Nodes of a LinkedList, or would you build a custom data structures consisting of two linked lists for both ends or similar?

Comment: Yes you need to create a custom LinkedList. with the class of Node and the class LinkedList with methods of inserting etc. where you would maintain head,last and middle pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need a data structure with 3 pointers.

A `doubly linked list` will be good. But , if you will use a `singly list list` (with pointers only in one direction), then you will either be able to only move right or left (not both at the same time). SLL wont serve the purpose.

See this for the implementation of a very similar problem: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-a-stack-with-find-middle-operation/

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you should use two `ArrayDeque`s, one for the first half of the the list and one for the last half. Move elements from one to the other to keep them the same size, so you always have access to the middle.

This will be faster and more memory-efficient than using `LinkedList`.